# Creating real time dashboard with help Amazon QuickSight + MySQL

Tags: quicksight-embedding, amazon-quicksight

My company use Amazon QuickSight at the moment, and faced a big problem when using this service. In short, we have a lot of dashboards that, unfortunately, are not updated in real time. We had tried to use real time parameters in QuickSight configuration when we create dashboards, but it did't work properly because QuickSight send request like

```
"Select * From SomeTable"
```

constantly and it takes a lot of time.

First because this 'SomeTable' it’s a view that executed several hours and then several hours we send via tcp result to QuickSight. It's all work extremely slow. Can you advice any solution that allow us to create real time updating? We need the following behavior:

1. QuickSight get all data from us sending query "Select * From SomeTable"
2. We send from our side any changes to Amazon QuickSight, that happens in our "SomeTable"

Please tell me is it possible to implement this behaviour for Amazon QuickSight? I'II be very grateful. Because we're really just stuck with this problem.

Comment: *"several hours we send via tcp result to QuickSight"*  There is no aggregation function in the query that would shrink the resultset?

Comment: unfortunately currently no

Comment: Do you display all data in tables? Because charts usually apply some aggregations for X/Y axes and groups.

Comment: Yes. We display a lot of different data.

Comment: I still don't understand your usecase. Let's say your resultset has 100M rows. Do you do put them all to a table? Nobody wants to browse such big tables (even though paginated)  I would then time-contain the table, e.g. show me the last day only. 
If you have aggregations then I would recommend you to pre-aggregate data into dedicated tables via ETL.
You can cache data to SPICE but refreshing SPICE means doing full-refresh. So you can't do it frequently.

Comment: Thanks PeterS for your help. It was very helpful.